# Where can I find my device's DPI?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nvidia-shield

I'm an android developer, and for that reason I have to find out how much DPI my tablet has. I looked through settings, device info and tried to google it but could not find anything clear enough. I'm looking for DPI, **NOT** PPI.

Looked through the default; Tests about it, but only PPI was mentioned. I really need the DPI.

Comment: Already tried the old-fashioned way (installing a Terminal emulator and issuing `getprop ro.sf.lcd_density`)?

Comment: no, but I managed to complete it using code